# Read JSON values by a specific term

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs, web

I have multiple JSON files and all of them have a "matching_terms" value. Example below:

```
{
  "calendar": [
    {
      "id": "12345",
      "title": "Acme Proposal Meeting",
      "invitees": "dave, john, bob, carol",
      "matching_terms": ["dave", "john", "bob", "carol", "acme"],
      "date": "2019-01-10 10:00:00"
    },
    {
      "id": "12345",
      "title": "Acme Final Delivery Meeting",
      "invitees": "dave, john, bob, alice",
      "matching_terms": ["dave", "john", "bob", "alice", "acme"],
      "date": "2019-03-01 11:00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am creating a search bar, when an input is received from the search bar it should go through all the JSON files and look in the matching_terms value if the given input is present in it or not. If it is present then we display that particular JSON block. I am using React to build it, till now I've created a search bar, what would be the next steps or things to follow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: By files you mean data entries or seperate json files?

Comment: Haven't tried anything yet, looking at some videos to learn how to do it.

Comment: I meant seperate Json files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you

```js
const block = {
  "calendar": [
    {
      "id": "12345",
      "title": "Acme Proposal Meeting",
      "invitees": "dave, john, bob, carol",
      "matching_terms": ["dave", "john", "bob", "carol", "acme"],
      "date": "2019-01-10 10:00:00"
    },
    {
      "id": "12345",
      "title": "Acme Final Delivery Meeting",
      "invitees": "dave, john, bob, alice",
      "matching_terms": ["dave", "john", "bob", "alice", "acme"],
      "date": "2019-03-01 11:00:00"
    }
  ]
}

function findSearchTerm(input) {
  block.calendar.forEach((e, idx) => {
    if(e.matching_terms.includes(input)) {
      console.log(e)
    } else {
      console.log("Term not found")
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do parse the JSON file like below. But what you want to implement was a search an object with given values. if its small number of JSON records then you can use Javascript filters otherwise you need some kind indexing algorithm to search the object

```js
var obj = JSON.parse(`{
  "calendar": [
    {
      "id": "12345",
      "title": "Acme Proposal Meeting",
      "invitees": ["dave", "john", "bob", "carol"],
      "matching_terms": ["dave", "john", "bob", "carol", "acme"],
      "date": "2019-01-10 10:00:00"
    },
    {
      "id": "1234",
      "title": "Acme Final Delivery Meeting",
      "invitees": ["dave", "john", "bob", "alice"],
      "matching_terms": ["dave", "john", "bob", "alice", "acme"],
      "date": "2019-03-01 11:00:00"
    }
  ]
}`);

console.log (obj.calendar[0].invitees)

let searchObj  = obj.calendar.filter(val => val.id === '1234')
console.log(searchObj[0])
```